# Why the bootstrap is not working with symfony 3.4.14

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4

I'm using symfony 3.4 for my Portfolio and I faced a very rare problem or maybe it's not a problem whenever I try my web in different device it keeps showing me all the elements too small I don't know why.
I'm using bootstrap CDNs I didn't download them so here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVCjg.png) that I took the right one is without symfony and the left one the with symfony. 
it is normal that symfony showing me like this or not. What should I do?

Comment: Doesn't really sound like a symfony problem. Based on the console error, looks like something that needs jquery (`$`) and isn't getting it. jQuery scripts should come first before the other scripts that needs them.

Comment: im talking about the image at the left the right one is working very well and the right is just an exmple if you see they both are in Pixel 2 but with different views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add bootstrap meta in your Base.html.twig ?
add this

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a symfony problem, it's strict frontend problem.

As Andrew Nolan responded it looks like there is no jquery loaded.

Check in a sourcecode / views(twig) if it's all ok with js/jquery?
- maybe you load jquery after your js code (and code don't have `$(document).ready()` ) ?

Comment: no that's not the problem the right image is working well but the left one isn't, it shows me all div in small and its kinda invisible. i didn't download the bootstrap i just use its CDNs in base.html.twig

Comment: Use GitHub gist and paste link here

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Bakhshi-Faisal/fb9e46cd9e0953668b7b681399981e81